# Is 終点 a correct way to refer to the last stop of a train route?

Tags: translation

I am wondering if 終点  is the correct translation to ''Last Stop''

Answer (score 2):

- 終点 is the end point/destination where a train stops in a service planning diagram.
- 終着駅 is the last train station explicitly stated in a service planning diagram.

終点 is often announced by a train officer aboard the train.

Note that neither indicates the end points on which a train may move. In a different schedule, another train might stops beyond the end point where your train stops or the end point might be extended.

Comment: When you say "service planning diagram" do you mean "timetable", or is this some more sophisticated concept that I'm not familiar with? I'm struggling to understand the difference between 終点 and 終着駅.

Comment: @user3856370 The [link](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0#/media/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Washington_Metro_diagram_sb.svg) shows a subway diagram you may see in a metropolitan area in the world. Not an ordinary person worries about the sophisticated concept a transportation company uses, so I think saying a timetable is fine. 「ダイヤの乱れ」is a set phrase when train delays due to off-schedule by some accidents.

Comment: Ah, I see you what you mean now. Not sure we have a good word for that in the UK. For the London Underground we'd say 'tube map', but for railways in general we don't really have such a concept. Just to clear up the difference between 終点 and 終着駅, would it be right to say that the 終点 is London and the 終着駅 is King's Cross, for example?

Comment: Japanese worry about punctuality, that’s the point. 終点 is used for the destination for a line you ride and it's more conceptual. I think 終着駅 can be interchangable in the same meaning, but I'd expect 終着駅 is the end point and you cannot physically see railway beyond. Probably King's Cross is the terminal for many lines. So if you leave at the station, it should be 終点/終着駅. If youu change a line, it should be 終点 for some line and moves to another origin callled 始発 for some line.

Comment: @user3856370 終着駅 is automatically 終点 if a train actually arrives there, but 終点 is not necessarily a 終着駅 (which is the case for most trains). For example 東海道本線 is technically from Tokyo to Kobe, but a train of 東海道本線 is usually bound for somewhere way before Kobe, e.g. Odawara, in which case 小田原 is  a 終点 but not 終着駅. I don't know this happens in UK, but it may be like a train of East Coast Main Line leaving London stops at Newcastle  and go no further, and Newcastle is a 終点. (I suppose leaving Edinburgh, it always goes to London so that London/King's Cross is always a 終着駅 and 終点 wrt ECML).

Comment: The above comment is for the sense given in the answer (like given in the comment, 終着駅 is ambiguous).

Comment: @sundowner 補足ありがとうございます。終着駅とは言うけど、やや比喩表現っぽいですよね。

Comment: 確かに歌詞とかせいぜい小説とかでしか見ない気がしますね。（少なくとも首都圏だと）そもそもあまり端っこという意味での終着駅があまりないのと、あちこちつながってて意識しないせいかもしれませんが。